# Authentication with JWT Token in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to handle the user authentication in Angluar with JWT tokens. If the Access Token is expired, the client asks for a new one using Refresh Token, which is stored on client side, in Local Storage. The program checks the validity of the Access Token before every requests. If it is valid, sends the request, if is not, it sends the request only after retrieving the new Token.

My problem: It generates unreasonably many requests, when the Access Token has expired, and returns with 401 status code (unauthorized), but at the end a new Access Token will be stored in the Local Storage. It runs into an infinite loop because it uses the expired token, when it calls addRefreshToken(), instead of waiting the new one.

How could I solve this problem? Could someone show me an example to find out where to start?

```
/*
 * HttpInterceptor:
*/

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
{
    if(!request.url.includes('authentication') 
        || !request.url.includes('authentication')) // Have token
    {
        if(this.tokenIsExpire()) // Token not Expire
        {
            return next.handle(this.addToken(request));
        }
        else // Token expired
        {
            this.addRefreshToken();
            return next.handle(this.addToken(request));
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        request=request.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: `Content-Type: Application/json`,}});
        return next.handle(request);    
    }
}

private tokenIsExpire():boolean
{
    let dateNow= new Date;
    let tokenExpire= new Date(localStorage.getItem('expires'));

    if(tokenExpire>dateNow)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
}

private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> 
{
    const token: string = this.auth.getToken();

    if (token) 
    {
        return request.clone(
        {
            setHeaders: 
            {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        });
    }
}

private addRefreshToken() 
{
    this.auth.getRefreshToken().subscribe((response) => 
        {                 
            localStorage.setItem('token',response['token']);
            localStorage.setItem('expires',response['expires']);
            localStorage.setItem('refreshtoken',response['refreshtoken']);

            localStorage.setItem(
                'refreshtokenexpires',response['refreshtokenexpires']);
        }        
    );      
}




/*
 *AuthService:
*/
registerUser(user):Observable<String[]>
{
    return this.http.get<String[]>(this._registerUrl);
}

getToken()
{
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

getrefreshtoken()
{
    return localStorage.getItem('refreshtoken');
}

getRefreshToken(): Observable<String>
{
    return this.http.get<String>(this.tokenURL);
}

getExpire():Observable<String>{
    return of(localStorage.getItem('expires'));
}

getrefreshtokenexpire()
{
    return localStorage.getItem('refreshtokenexpires');
}
```

Comment: don't you have to use the refresh token to fetch a new access token? I don't see that happening in your code

Comment: In this test I did not use the refresh token, but that part of the program works separately from the access token's fetching.

Comment: I wouldn't check the tokens validity with each request, I would write an HTTP error handler that deals with 401 responses by attempting to refresh the token. If the refresh token fails I would log the user out and get a new JWT.

Comment: I have tried, but it always sends the request with the old token. Maybe could you/someone link something useable guide please?